# PhantomJS failed to load your page. Use --force to continue

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I am trying to run test with grunt-contrib-jasmine trough command line "grunt jasmine", but its fails giving the warning :  "PhantomJS failed to load your page. Use --force to continue."...

base.spec.js:

```
describe('Namespace',function(){
    it('Provides the global *** object',function(){
        expect(***).to.be.an('object');
        expect(***).to.include.keys('App','Templates');
    });
});
```

gruntfile.js including this:

```
jasmine : {
    src : ['apps/<%=target%>/js/**/*.js'],
        options : {
            host : 'http://127.0.0.1:5000', 
            specs : 'tests/<%=target%>/**/*spec.js',
        }
},
.
.
.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
```

Can't understand what is wrong...

Please help, Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

In gruntfile.js make your src: 'apps/<%=target%>/js/**/FileName',
(remove the .js after filename)

Add this before jasmine:
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

connect: {
    test : {
      port : 8000,
      base: 'test'
    }

},

set a default task so it can perform connection and then execute:
grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect','jasmine']);

if it yet fails then try doing grunt jasmine --force to know where its failing